# android accessibility service description not change when switch local language

Tags: android, accessibility

I create an accessibility service on android, in the manifest.xml file I declare the service with meta-data, and the resource tag references to an config.xml file which has the item `android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"` Then in the values directory I have two string named accessibility_service_description in Chinese and English. What I expect is when I switch language, the description content will change. However, the description is the same, when I switch from English to Chinese. The same problem occur when switch from Chinese.  The problem is when I install the application, the description content will be the same as the language then. So I don't think it is the strings' problem, is there any thing else i need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything right. It's a framework bug that was fixed in Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean).

Comment: thank you, I thought it as a framework bug as well. It's glad to know which version has fixed it. Thank you again.